# EF objects behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Whenever i am changing an Entity Object reference changes are reflected to all other previous Objects that point to the same Entity. example:

```
   var menu = menuRepo.FindByByIdAsync(12);
   var menu1 = menuRepo.FindByByIdAsync(12);
   menu.Name = "Name";
   Console.WriteLine(menu.Name+ " "+ menu1.Name);
```

At this point if i run the code snippet both menu and menu1 are changed. 
Is this happening because of the Entity's Proxies? I dont really understand it. If those two Objects where Class Objects they would have different names...how is this possible?

**EDIT**

Even stranger is the Orderby scenario i have tried...

```
 var menu = menuRepo.FindById(1);
 menu.MenuItems.OrderBy(m => m.OrderField).ToList();
```

these 2 lines actually order the items collection inside the menu Object.

I dont even have to set them...???

```
 menu.MenuItems = menu.MenuItems.OrderBy(m => m.OrderField).ToList();
```

Comment: Try checking 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(menu == menu1)' - you should find they are the same object. This is because EF caches them.

Comment: OrderBy<T> returns a new instance of a IOrderedEnumerable<T>. It doesn't do an inplace sort.  I believe your diagnostics are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF keeps only one instance of the same object in its context; FindByIdAsync retrieve the item having Id = 12 and set a reference of it in the context. The second time you call FindByIdAsync it returns a reference from the context to the same object. So that is why when you change the property in the first object the corresponding  property in the second object is changed as well.

OrderBy  dosen't return the ordered collection itself;  the returned value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the sort.

The sorting is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach.

```
menu.MenuItems.OrderBy(m => m.OrderField)
```

dosen't execute any sort

```
menu.MenuItems.OrderBy(m => m.OrderField).ToList();
```

execute the sort because ToList() is invoked